# Difference in ps priority vs top priority output

Tags: linux, bash, shell, process

Here is top and ps output I got on ubuntu version 14.04.1:

```
$ ps -o pid,ppid,pri,ni,cmd -p 1
  PID  PPID PRI  NI CMD
    1     0  19   0 /sbin/init
$ ps -o pid,ppid,pri,ni,cmd -p 2
  PID  PPID PRI  NI CMD
    2     0  19   0 [kthreadd]
```

Top Output:

```
 PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
    1 root      20   0    4616   3752   2584 S   0.0  0.1   0:01.84 init
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.11 kthreadd
    3 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.36 ksoftirqd/0
    5 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H
```

My question is Why there is a difference in priority output of top and ps command? In top output priority value is one higher than the ps output.This is also true for the user processes.

Edit:

```
 $ps -o pid,ppid,pri,ni,cmd -p 5
 PID  PPID PRI  NI CMD
  5     2  39 -20 [kworker/0:0H]
```

Comment: This is very interesting. Could you add `ps -o pid,ppid,pri,ni,cmd -p 5` to your first output? I wanna see if NICE values differ too.

Comment: @alok Added ps -o pid,ppid,pri,ni,cmd -p 5 output.

Comment: I have opened an issue as I have seen the same behaviour. https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/issues/111

Answer (score 0):

I think, 'ps -o' is Unix style which is different to top's BSD style.

Try Unix style ps( without '-')

```
ps al
```